# c# Как правильно реализовать исключение

Tags: c#, исключения

Хочу научиться пользоваться исключениями. Пожалуйста скажите правильно ли я всё делаю? И как правильно это делать? (метод CheckMove) Как можно обработать?

```
abstract class ChessPiece
{
    protected int x, y;
    public abstract void MakeMove(int x, int y);

    protected virtual bool CheckMove(int x, int y)
    {
        return x >= 0 && x <= 8 && y >= 0 && y <= 8;
    }
}

class Rock : ChessPiece
{
    public override void MakeMove(int x, int y)
    {
        if (!CheckMove(x, y))
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Parametr cannot be less than 0 and greater than 8");
        }
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    protected override bool CheckMove(int x, int y)
    {
        return (this.x == x || this.y == y) && base.CheckMove(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, вполне. Только не забывайте, что исключения надо не только порождать, но еще отлавливать и что-то делать: либо обрабатывать, либо пробрасывать еще выше по коду тому, кто будет обрабатывать. У вас это получается будет какой-то UI, который поймает исключение и сообщит, что ладья походила неправильно.

Comment: почему бы не создавать это исключение прямо внутри функции `CheckMove`? Или вы везде будете копипастить текст исключения, при каждой проверке?

Comment: + нужно описать в документации метода в блоке <exception> что за тип ошибки метод может выбросить и коротко, в каких случаях её ожидать. Так же можно обойтись вообще без исключений - переименовать метод на TryMakeMove и возвращать false, если ход выполнить нельзя, а в качестве out параметра метода или второго выходного строкового параметра (в виде tuple<bool, string>) вернуть причину и отображать в UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Пожалуйста скажите правильно ли я всё делаю?

Если я правильно понимаю смысл кода - нет, неправильно. Вы собираетесь бросать исключение ArgumentException, когда пользователь пытается выполнить ход, не соответствующий тому, как ходит фигура по правилам шахмат. Это не выглядит исключительной ситуацией. Зачем выполнять достаточно тяжелую для CLR операцию проброса исключения для того, что можно решить простым возвратом значения? Я понимаю проброс ArgumentException, когда координаты за пределами доски, так как это обычно означает баг в коде, в этом случае можно бросать исключение.

Другое замечание: CheckMove - неудачное наименование для метода проверки, неясно, что именно означает true - корректность или некорректность.

По мне должно быть как-то так:

```
class MoveResult
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

abstract class ChessPiece
{
    protected int x, y;
    public virtual MoveResult MakeMove(int x, int y)
    {
        AssertCoordinatesValid(x, y);

        if (!IsMoveValid(x, y))
        {
            return new MoveResult
            {
                IsValid = false,
                Message = "This move is not allowed for " + this.GetType().ToString()
            };
        }
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        return new MoveResult { IsValid = true, Message = "" };
    }

    static void AssertCoordinatesValid(int x, int y)
    {        
        if (!(x >= 0 && x <= 8 && y >= 0 && y <= 8))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Coordinates cannot be less than 0 or greater than 8");
        }
    }

    protected abstract bool IsMoveValid(int x, int y);
}

class Rock : ChessPiece
{
    protected override bool IsMoveValid(int x, int y)
    {       
        return (this.x == x || this.y == y);
    }
}
```